# c++ constructor lnk2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, constructor, lnk2019

I've been learning C++ for the last term, and I'm currently working on a database project.

After working on this project for a while, and troubleshooting this last weekend, I'm finally down to an error which I believe is the root of the problem.
It seems to be a problem with the constructor, although I can't quite put my finger on it.

This is the output feedback:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: database, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>database.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Member::Member(void)" (??0Member@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Database::Database(class Database const &)" (??0Database@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)
1>database.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Member::output(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?output@Member@@QAEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Database::search(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?search@Database@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>database.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Member &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVMember@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Database::save(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?save@Database@@QAEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>database.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Member &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVMember@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Database::load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?load@Database@@QAEXAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ
```

Here's the snippet of the database.cpp file where I believe I've identified the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "database.h"
using namespace std;

Database::Database()
{
    used = 0;
    capacity = 6;
    data = new Member[capacity];
}
Database::Database(const Database& other)                       // Copy-constructor
{
    used = other.used;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    data = new Member[capacity];
    copy(other.data, other.data + used, data);
}
Database::~Database()                                           // De-constructor
{
    delete[]data;
}
void Database::operator =(const Database& other)
{
    if (&other == this)                                         // Equility Overloader     sikrer emp1 = emp2
    {
        return;
    }
    delete[]data;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    used = other.used;
    data = new Member[capacity];
    copy(other.data, other.data + used, data);
}
```

Here's the complete database.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "database.h"

using namespace std;

Database::Database()
{
    used = 0;
    capacity = 6;
    data = new Member[capacity];
}
Database::Database(const Database& other)                       // Copy-constructor
{
    used = other.used;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    data = new Member[capacity];
    copy(other.data, other.data + used, data);
}
Database::~Database()                                           // De-constructor
{
    delete[]data;
}
void Database::operator =(const Database& other)
{
    if (&other == this)                                         // Equility Overloader     sikrer emp1 = emp2
    {
        return;
    }
    delete[]data;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    used = other.used;
    data = new Member[capacity];
    copy(other.data, other.data + used, data);
}
void Database::make_bigger()
{
    Member* tmp;
    tmp = new Member[capacity + 6];
    copy(data, data + used, tmp);
    delete[]data;
    data = tmp;
    capacity += 6;
}
void Database::search(string name)
{
    int antall_funn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].get_name() == name)
        {
            cout << "Klassemedlem funnet!" << endl;
            data[i].output(cout);
            antall_funn++;
        }
    }
    if (antall_funn == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ingen klassemedlemmer med det navnet funnet!" << endl;
    }
}
void Database::search_id(int id)
{
    int antall_funn = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < used;i++)
    {
        if (data[i].get_id_number() == id)
        {
            cout << "Klassemedlem funnet!" << endl;
            data[i].output(cout);
            antall_funn++;
        }
    }
    if (antall_funn == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ingen klassemedlemmer med det navnet funnet!" << endl;
    }
}
void Database::add(const Member& emp)
{
    if (used >= capacity)
    {
        make_bigger();
    }
    data[used] = emp;
    used++;
}
void Database::show_all()
{
    for (int i = 0;i < used;i++)
    {
        data[i].output(cout);
    }
}
void Database::remove(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < used;i++)
    {
        if (data[i].get_name() == name)
        {
            data[i] = data[used - 1];
            used--;
        }
    }
}
void Database::save(ostream& outs)
{
    sort_name();
    for (int i = 0;i < used;i++)
    {
        outs << data[i];
    }
}
void Database::load(istream& ins)
{
    Member tmp;
    while (ins >> tmp)
    {
        if (used >= capacity)
        {
            make_bigger();
        }
        data[used] = tmp;
        used++;
    }
}
void Database::sort_name()
{
    bool ferdig = false;
    Member tmp;
    while (!ferdig)
    {
        ferdig = true;                                              // Bytter første variabel i arrayen med neste dersom den første er større.
        for (int i = 0;i < used - 1;i++)
        {
            if (data[i].get_name() > data[i + 1].get_name())
            {
                ferdig = false;
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i + 1];
                data[i + 1] = tmp;

            }
        }
    }
}
void Database::sort_income()
{
    bool ferdig = false;
    Member tmp;
    while (!ferdig)
    {
        ferdig = true;                                              // Bytter første variabel i arrayen med neste dersom den første er større.
        for (int i = 0;i < used - 1;i++)
        {
            if (data[i].get_income() > data[i + 1].get_income())
            {
                ferdig = false;
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i + 1];
                data[i + 1] = tmp;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my database.h header:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H
#include "member.h"

class Database
{
    public:
        
        Database();
        ~Database();
        Database(const Database& other);
        void operator =(const Database& other);
        void search(std::string name);
        void search_id(int id);
        void add(const Member& emp);
        void show_all();
        void remove(std::string name);
        void save(std::ostream& outs);
        void load(std::istream& ins);
        void sort_name();
        void sort_income();

    private:
        void make_bigger();
        int capacity;
        Member *data;
        int used;

        
};
#endif
```

And here's my member.h header:

```
#ifndef MEMBER_H
#define MEMBER_H

class Member
{
    public:
        Member();
        Member(std::string new_name, int new_id, std::string new_address, double new_income, std::string new_topposition, int new_yearsworked);
        //accesors
        std::string get_name()const{return name;}
        int get_id_number()const{ return id_number; }
        std::string get_address()const{ return address; }
        double get_income()const{ return income; }
        std::string get_topposition()const{ return topposition; }
        int get_yearsworked()const{ return yearsworked; }
        void output(std::ostream& outs);
        void input(std::istream& ins);
    private:
        std::string name;
        int id_number;
        std::string address;    
        double income;
        std::string topposition;
        int yearsworked;
};
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, Member& tmp);
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& ins, Member& tmp);
#endif
```

Here's the complete member.cpp:
shouldn't it only be the member::member and database::database which provides the malfunction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "member.h"
using namespace std;

Member::Member()
{
    id_number = 0;
    income = 0;
    yearsworked = 0;
}
Member::Member(std::string new_name, int new_id, std::string new_address, double new_income, std::string new_topposition, int new_yearsworked)
{
    name = new_name;
    id_number = new_id;
    address = new_address;
    income = new_income;
    topposition = new_topposition;
    yearsworked = new_yearsworked;
}``
void Member::output(ostream& outs)
{
    if (outs.fail() == cout.fail())
    {
        outs << "Navn: " << name << endl;
        outs << "ID nummer: " << id_number << endl;
        outs << "Adresse: " << address << endl;
        outs << "L\x9Bnn: " << income << endl;
        outs << "H\x9Byeste stilling gjennom karrieren: " << topposition << endl;
        outs << "Anttal \x86r i Forsvaret: " << yearsworked << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        outs << name << endl;
        outs << id_number << endl;
        outs << address << endl;
        outs << income << endl;
        outs << topposition << endl;
        outs << yearsworked << endl;
    }
}
void Member::input(istream & ins)
{
    if (ins.fail() == cin.fail())
    {
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        cout << "Navn: ";
        getline(ins, name);
        cout << "Skriv inn ID nummer: ";
        ins >> id_number;
        cout << "Skriv inn adresse: ";
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        getline(ins, address);
        cout << "Skriv inn l\x9Bnn: ";
        ins >> income;
        cout << "Skriv inn toppstilling i Forsvaret: ";
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        getline(ins, topposition);
        cout << "Skriv inn antall \x86 ansatt i Forsvaret: ";
        ins >> yearsworked;
    }
    else {
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        getline(ins, name);
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        ins >> id_number;
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        getline(ins, address);
        if (ins.peek() == '\n')ins.ignore();
        getline(ins, topposition);
        ins >> income;
        ins >> yearsworked;
    }
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, Member& tmp)
{
    tmp.output(outs);
    return outs;
}
istream& operator >>(istream& ins, Member& tmp)
{
    tmp.input(ins);
    return ins;
}
```

The main.cpp makes a menu where you can select whether to add, delete, show members in the database. Added mainly for clarification.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "database.h"
using namespace std;

int meny();
int main()
{
    Database database;
    Member emp;
    string filename;
    cout << "Skriv inn filnavnet: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    filename + ".txt";
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
    if (!fin.fail())
    {
        database.load(fin);
        fin.close();
        int key = 0;
        while (key != 8)
        {
            key = meny();
            switch (key)
            {


            ...
            A whole bunch of keys
            ...


            }
        }
    }

        ofstream fout(filename.c_str());
        if (!fout.fail())
        {
            database.save(fout);
        }
        else {
            cout << "File could not open." << endl;
        }
        fout.close();
        cout << "Thank you for using the database!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "File doesn't exist, creating new." << endl;
        ofstream new_file(filename.c_str());
        new_file.close();
        main();
    }
    return 0;
}
int meny()
{
    int key;

    ...

    a whole bunch of couts and cin

    ...

    return key;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your `Member.h` makes a whole bunch of promises about implementations that are seemingly somewhere else. So... where are they? My crystal ball tells me there in the one cpp file you're (a) not building and linking with your project, and (b) didn't bother to show here, though you showed two other files that are barely-if-ever related. Somewhere a `Member.cpp` file either exists and isn't being included in your project, or doesn't which makes the former somewhat by-default. The lack of `main` suggests you're trying to build a library, but that's pure guesswork.

Comment: @WhozCraig Missed the member.cpp file yeah, added it now. And the main builds the menu for the program. Tried to keep only the parts of the code linked to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

because you forgot the implementation of

```
Member();
```

provide an explicit implementation or simply

```
Member() = default;
```

would solve the issue.

Comment: I had missed uploading the member.cpp file here, but it is now. As far as I can tell, it should be implemented here.

Comment: then you still missing the implementation of Member::output() and Member::input().

Comment: Added the complete member.cpp.

Comment: Added only the first bit earlier as I thought that was the part which gave the error.

Comment: sorry! I can't reproduce the issue. After adding all files to the project, and create a driver main.cpp with the following code:
```
int main() {
    Database db;
    return 0;
}
```
The project build succeeded:
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: hmm, weird. Do you think the problem might be within my main.cpp file?  The output and error list does send me back to line 1 in database.cpp.

Comment: I'll upload the main.cpp file, although it uses mainly a simple switch after having called upon the databases.

Comment: you still need the implementation for Database::save() and Database::load(). :-)

Comment: Updated with all the complete files, now. Many thanks for all the help Fetag :)

Comment: well, I don't have any compiled issue with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.2.

Comment: Interesting, and you just made a new project and copy pasted it all in?

Comment: Alright, copy/pasted everything over. Same issue. Currently running Visual Studio Community 2019 16.0.3. This time I also got 'C4834 discarding return value of function with 'no discard' attribute'  for the plus in this line: `filename + ".txt";`. Still believe that may be rooted in the previous problem.

Comment: Cheers, redid it again, suddenly worked. Don't really know what was the issue, but it does work now. Thank you for all the help :)